# Enter data from attendance sheet into phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, database

Inserting multiple record in phpmyadmin att table keeping all the information same except attendance and student id after clicking the submit button.Its taking only one last row without attendance status.I'm fetching attendance sheet from database.I have been stuck here in my first php project.

faculty panel

```
<form  action="<?php $PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">

<li><b>Select Courses :</b> <select name="courses" id="courses" class="form- 
 control action" >
<option value="">Courses</option>
<?php echo $courses; ?></select></li><br/>
<li><b>Select Semesters :</b> <br><select name="semesters" id="semesters" 
class="form-control action" >
<option value="">Semesters</option></select></li><br/>
<li><b>Select Subjects :</b><br> <select name="subjects" id="subjects" 
class="form-control " >
<option value="">Subjects</option></select>
<br/>
<li><b>Session No:<b><br/><input type="text" name="session_no" 
id="session_no" placeholder ="Session No" class="form-control">
<br>
<label class="control-label" for="date">Date</label>
<br/>
<input  class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" 
type="date"/>
<br/>
<li><b>Enter time:</b></li><br/>
From :<input type="time" name="time_from" id="time_from" class="form- 
control"/> </li><li>
<br/>
To   :<input type="time" name="time_to" id="time_to" class="form-control"/> 
</li></div>
<br>
<li><label class="btn btn-info">Display attendance sheet</label> </li>
<br/>

//attendance table
<table id = "table" class = "table table-bordered">
                <thead class = "alert-info">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <th>Firstname</th>
                        <th>Lastname</th>
                        <th>Present</th>
                        <th>Absent</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $q_student = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `student`") 
                          or die(mysqli_error());
                        while($f_student = $q_student->fetch_array()){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="student_no" value="<?php echo 
                            $f_student['student_no']?>" class="form-control" 
                            readonly/></td>
                        <td><?php echo $f_student['firstname']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $f_student['lastname']?></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="attendance[<?php echo 
                        $f_student['student_no']; ?>]" value="1" 
                        class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="attendance[<?php echo 
                        $f_student['student_no']; ?>]" value="0" 
                     class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                        <?php
                        }               
                        ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
<?php
        //Insert Record into attendancetable
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {   
              foreach ($_POST['attendance'] as $attendance){
              $faculty_id = 
             mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['faculty_id']);
              $student_no = 
               mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['student_no']);
              $courses = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['courses']);
              $semesters = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['semesters']);
              $subjects = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['subjects']);
              $session_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['session_no']);
              $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['date']);
              $time_from = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['time_from']);
              $time_to = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['time_to']);
              $attendance=var_dump($_POST['attendance']);
              $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_sars");
              $ins="INSERT INTO att( faculty_id,student_no,courses,semesters,subjects,session_no,date,time_from,time_to,attendance_status)
              VALUES ('$faculty_id','$student_no','$courses','$semesters','$subjects','$session_no','$date','$time_from','$time_to','$attendance')"; 
              }
              if(@mysqli_query($conn,$ins))
            {
              echo "inserted";
            }
              else
            {
              die(@mysqli_error());
            }

        }
        ?><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"  class="btn btn-info"></form>
```

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST['attendance']);`

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: It is taking only one row with details of student without attendance status.I want to submit whole attendance sheet with same details like course ,semester ,subject of all students by changing student_no and attendance.

Comment: See my answer regarding the attendance. However, are you also wanting to do multiple students at a time or just a single row (student) insert at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted, you are not assigning the attendance data (`$_POST['attendance']`) to the `$attendance` variable due to use of `var_dump`.

You wrote:

> `$attendance=var_dump($_POST['attendance']);`

From the php manual for [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

> **Return Values**
>
> No value is returned.

Instead, try formatting this line like you did all the rest:

```
$attendance = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['attendance']);
```

---

### Adding multiple students at a time- update

It appears that you are printing each student id in the front end table. I think that would be a better field to loop with. However, with your current front end code, it is creating a new post variable for each student id. Instead you probably want this instead:

```
<td><input name="student_no" value="StudentID[<?php echo $f_student['student_no']?>]" class="form-control" readonly/></td>
```

Note how this turns the student id into an array of student ids rather than a ton of different variables of each student ID.

Then for your foreach:

```
foreach ($_POST['StudentID'] as $StudentID) {
```

`$StudentID` is now updated for each iteration and allows you to look up the appropriate index in the other arrays. And you would change the pertinent rows as:

```
$student_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$StudentID); // The student ID is set by as in foreach
$StudentAttendance = $_POST['attendance'][$StudentID]; // Get the attendance status by looking up the student by student id in the attendance array
$attendance=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$StudentAttendance); // Escape input to avoid table disasters (reference Little Bobby Tables)
```

I haven't tested your code and understand that there is a lot more going on than this. However, it's probably best to tackle one thing at a time. **What you have to do is create a loop to go over each student, and each field that you want to collect should be posted as an array with an index for each student by their student id.**

Using `var_dump` is useful for understanding what a variable contains (for instance, it would help us to see what your variables contain if you would post the var_dump output with your question). If you have error messages, please post them as it helps guide us in the right direction as we attempt to help you out.

Comment: Okay, well it looks like you want an array if you are wanting to do all students at a time. Is that your goal? Or do you just want one student (row) at a time?

Comment: I have done this already it gives me Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given .I also worked on this error not able solve this.Any help would be greatly appreciated.I have gone through foreach loop concept tried differently but the problem for me is how to insert this data in table using for each loop in att table with repetitive details.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to achieve now. You might try to get just the student ID and attendance working first. Then work on all of the other fields. See updated answer.

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\att\faculty\home.php:135:
array (size=3)
  1234 => string '1' (length=1)
  1235 => string '0' (length=1)
  1236 => string '1' (length=1)

C:\wamp64\www\att\faculty\home.php:135:
array (size=3)
  1234 => string '1' (length=1)
  1235 => string '0' (length=1)
  1236 => string '1' (length=1)

C:\wamp64\www\att\faculty\home.php:135:
array (size=3)
  1234 => string '1' (length=1)
  1235 => string '0' (length=1)
  1236 => string '1' (length=1)
This is the output using var_dump.1234,1235,1236 are student_no.

Comment: I assume that's `$_POST['attendance']`? That's what's expected. So to find each one as you go through the loop, you look it up by `$_POST['attendance'][$StudentID]`. For example, `$_POST['attendance'][1234]` would = `1`.

Comment: Awesome! You are welcome. Alert me if you have further roadblocks, and please upvote/select answer if it was useful to you.